# how to compress a group of files into a zip file in objective c using zlib (Example)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, zlib

i'm working in a project that compress a group of files as a one zip file, i want to use the built in framework (zlib) to avoid any linking or any other types of errors that other types of frameworks like objective zip may expose,so i want any sample code that discuss how to use this library,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at [objective-zip](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/).

Example:

```
ZipWriteStream *stream= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:@"abc.txt" compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelBest];
[stream writeData:abcData];
[stream finishedWriting];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library: [ZipKit](https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/Home)